# count the number of occurrences for each variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, count

Here is my data frame (tibble) `df`:

```
   ENSG00000000003 ENSG00000000005 ENSG00000000419 ENSG00000000457 ENSG00000000460
             <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
 1              61               0              70               0               0
 2               0               0             127               0               0
 3             318               0               2               0               0
 4               1               0               0               0               0
 5               1               0              67               0               0
 6               0               0               0             139               0
 7               0               0               0               0               0
 8             113               0               0               0               0
 9               0               0               1               0               0
10               0               0               0               1               0
```

For each column/variable, I would like to count the number of rows with value greater than 10. In this case, column 1 would be 3, column 2 would be zero, etc. This is a test data frame, and I would like to do this for many columns.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `colSums` on a logical matrix

```
colSums(df > 10, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   summarise_all(~ sum(. > 10, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. I like the dplyr solution better.? I've been told that I'll be better off learning the dplyr way.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise_all(~sum(.>10))
```

will do what you want.